# What is a non-clustered index scan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, index, nonclustered-index

I know what table scan, clustered index scan and index seek is but my google skills let me down to find a precise explanation into non clustered index scans. Why and when a query uses a non clustered index scan?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A non-clustered index scan may be chosen in this scenario:

1. the optimizer determines that it is cheaper to scan all rows rather than perform seeks/range scans
2. the non-clustered index is "skinnier" than the clustered index
3. the non-clustered still covers the columns needed by the query (or it covers enough of them and a lookup for the remainder is still cheaper than a clustered index scan)

It can also happen, obviously, if you have a heap (no clustered index) and 3. is still true.

*This is not meant to be an exhaustive list - there are other cases where a non-clustered index scan may be chosen, but this is probably the most common.*

Comment: Hi Aaron. I'm sure you are right but it's me that couldn't quite get it :( So think about this query select * from tableX where name='anyName' and we have a nonclustered index (let index name be: ncName) on name column. Please correct me if I'm wrong but optimizer would either do a seek on ncName or scan on clustering key. Where does nc scan fits here? Thanks.

Comment: Non-clustered index scan shouldn't be chosen there unless there are a *lot* of rows that match a specific name (or statistics are way off-base). For a few rows, it might make more sense to do an index seek on the name column coupled with a lookup to get the other columns in `*`. But unless there is more to the story I don't see off-hand why a non-clustered index scan would be chosen in that case.

Comment: What about non-clustered index scan performed whilst calculating an aggregate on a table? Comparing with your scenario given: 1. Cost is not relevant as it is necessary to scan all rows. 2. Even if non-clustered index is as narrow (No, I am not going to say “skinnier”!) as clustered – non-clustered will still be preferred. 3. Non-clustered index not necessarily may cover columns needed by the query.

Comment: @Pavel sure, I wasn't saying "This is the ONLY case where a non-clustered index scan would be chosen." Especially given the follow-up comment by the OP. Anyway, I'd argue your scenario still fits into #1 - cost is absolutely considered. You're getting an aggregate that could be satisfied by an NC or CIX scan; SQL Server is going to choose the cheaper one. If they're the same, it's a coin toss.

Comment: Just wondering if you are aware of any examples when given equal cost CI will be preferred over NC?

Comment: @Pavel way too broad. Can you narrow down the scenario just a little bit, please? Anyway, I still think you're out in left field with "cost is not relevant" - in cases where an NC is preferred over CI, what factor(s) do you think make it preferred, if not cost?

Comment: OK. For example you are saying in case of an aggregate if cost of CI and NC is the same it's a coin toss. This means there are situations when CI wins. Never had those in practice and thought (it seems like I was wrong) that NC is ALWAYS preferred over CI. Any chance you can provide an example involving an aggregate when CI wins?

Comment: No, I did not say that. A coin toss could always land heads, and SQL Server might always choose the NC. I don't know of any rule that **guarantees** SQL Server will always choose the NC. If that's what you're looking for, you've come to the wrong place.